# How to access changing instance variables (due to a loop) in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, ajax, instance-variables

I am trying to use AJAX to append images to a div container.  My photos have a URL field, and so I tried to create an instance variable to then throw inside a div tag like `<div id="individual-photo" data-url="<%= @photo_url %>">`.

This didn't work, because it assigned one value for that instance variable and when I called it in my .js `var url = $("#individual-photo").data("url");`, it gave me the same image for all future photos.

I found that solution in another StackOverflow and I think that would work if I wasn't working with a div generated through a loop.. so my question is, seeing as how I am using a loop.. how do I communicate this information to my .js file?

This is the code in my index.html.erb

```
<div id="sidescrolling-container">
      <% if @page > 1 %>
        <%= link_to "PREV", (next_path(@link - 2) + "/#individual-photo") %>
      <% end %>

      <% @pics.each do |photo| %>
        <% @pic_id = photo.id%>
        <% @photo_url = Photo.where(id: @pic_id)[0].url %>
        <div id="individual-photo" data-url="<%= @photo_url %>">

          <img src="<%= photo.url %>" height='250px' width="250px">
          <span id="photo-title"><%= photo.title %></span>
        </div>
      <% end %>

      <% if @page < @page_max %>
        <%= link_to "NEXT", (next_path(@link) + "/#individual-photo"), id: "next_button" %>
      <% end %>

    </div>
```

and my .js

```
var images = $.get("photos/" + page, function(data){
      var info = $("#individual-photo", data).each(function(){
          var title = $("#photo-title", this).text();

          var url = $("#individual-photo").data("url");

          $("#sidescrolling-container").append(
              '<div id="individual-photo"><img src="'+url+'" height="250px" width="250px"><span id="photo-title">'+title+'</span></div>'
            )
      })
    })
```

If there's a better way to go about this I'd love to know more!  Just no gem solutions please, I don't want to use gems for this part of my code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`$("#individual-photo")` references every individual photo in your *complete* DOM, `$("#individual-photo").data()` always references the data properties of the *first* element in this selection. Therefore, you always get the the first url.

It should be

```
var images = $.get("photos/" + page, function(data){
    $("#individual-photo", data).each(function(){
        var title = $("#photo-title", this).text();

        var url = $(this).data("url");

        $("#sidescrolling-container").append(
            '<div id="individual-photo"><img src="'+url+'" height="250px" width="250px"><span id="photo-title">'+title+'</span></div>'
        )
    })
})
```

Comment: Maybe it would have occured to you earlier if you had written valid XML syntax, i. e. assigning id properties only when they are unique. In this case, marking the div as `<div class="individual-photo" ...>` would make it semantically clearer that these elements occur multiple times.

Comment: ccprog, THIS is what I needed!  Thank you! :P  I definitely need to get better at id's vs classes.